# Creating a Stored Procedure with variables

Tags: stored-procedures

I'm stuck on a homework question and am looking for a little help with understanding this process.

4. Stored Procedure with Output Parameters

c. Build a SP that passes in empID and returns an output parameter of the mgrID

d.  (Start a New Query and separate it from the previous Stored Procedure) Declare an "empid int" and "manager_name Varchar(50)" variable

e.  Hard code your new "empid" variable and Pass it into your new SP to return the "mgrid"

f.  Capture that "mgrid" in a variable and use that "mgrid" variable to determine the Managers name
(Create another statement which locates the Manager’s Name by using mgrID)

e.  Print the Managers name

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to determine the appropriate response. However, when assigning a single field to a variable (as for printing) I've used something along the lines of:

`@Manager_Name = (SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM EmployeeTable WHERE EmployeeID = @MgrID)`